# Select columns from different tables, without creating a combination of different rows?

Tags: sql, db2

lets say I have `tableA` which has a `col1` and `tableB` which has `col2` with the following content:

```
Table A
---------
A
B
C
D


Table B
---------
1
2
3
4
```

I want a select statement that returns to me:

```
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
D, 4
```

I have tried making this call:

```
Select tableA.col1, tableB.col2 from tableA, tableB
```

but it returns the following:

```
A, 1
B, 1
C, 1
D, 1
A, 2
..
..
 etc
```

how can i get it to just pull back this:

```
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
D, 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select b.val1, b.val1, c.val2 from tableA a
inner join (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNumber, col1 as val1 from tableA) on a.col1 = b.val1
inner join (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNumber, col2 as val2 from tableB) c on c.RowNumber = b.RowNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just a side question, if I for some reason wanted to get the value from tableA twice to get something like this:

``A, A, 1
B, B, 2
C, C, 3
D, D, 4``

what would I have to add to your statement?

Comment: I get the following error trying to run the statement:

``SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'RowNumber'" was found following 
"col1) AS".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  
SQLSTATE=42601``

Comment: @Sean, I've edit my answer. But for that, you just need another `col1` in your `select`.

Comment: @Sean I've edit again, try it both and tell me the error if it gives.

Comment: Ok I tried that and it now gives this error:

`SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'val1'" was found following "mber, col1 
as".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'val1'" was found following "mber, LOCATION_PK as".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>`

And when I removed the quote from val1 and val2 it gives this error:

`SQL0206N  "A.VAL" is not valid in the context where it is used.  
SQLSTATE=42703`

Comment: the problem was that I forgot that we don't use quotes on DB2 and one column was wrong :)